# My laravel application is displaying no data

Tags: php, laravel-4, apache2

```
    ## My laravel application is displaying no data ##
```

Hi gues, I am working on a questionniare application using laravel framework i ran into this issue i cannnot figure it out. when i type mquestions.com my server just goes white screen, no data is recieved, and when i do a chrome inspector check i get a 500 internal server error. Although i set my server to virtual host instead of using the normal localhost for my development enviroment. this is my apache settings for virtual host `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-conf` this is what i setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/websiteclient/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/websiteclient/public/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ServerName mquestions.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and in my `/etc/hosts` file this is what i have,

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Jobinpal
127.0.1.1   popibay.com
127.0.1.1   billishop.com
127.0.1.1   mquestions.com
127.0.1.1   stackedit
127.0.1.1   phpmyadmin
127.0.1.1   opencart
```

then when i do a `$ sudo apache2ctl restart` in the command line

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

also my **app/storage** is already set to RW mode.

Sincerely i don`t know if it is a laravel issue or a apache2 issue,So gues what is the problem and what is the sollution. Thanks

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the DirectoryIndex declaration, as follows (at least, I have it on this way, and so far it is working):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName YOUR_SERVER_NAME
    DocumentRoot YOUR_FOLDER_LOCATION
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory YOUR_FOLDER_LOCATION>
       AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do you mean directory index? @facundofarias

Comment: If you check it, inside of your YOUR_FOLDER_LOCATION you have an index.php file which bootstrap the Laravel startup.

Comment: so do you mean i should add the index.php to the folder location like this DirectoryIndex index.php

Comment: No, you only need to include the DirectoryIndex declaration on the VirtualHost xml node